# Not understanding the recurrence formula of n nodes with a height h in an AVL tree to show h <= 2 log n

Tags: recursion, avl-tree, recurrence, proof

I know the formula is: `n(h) = n(h-1) + n(h-2) + 1`

And I know it can be reduced as:

```
n(h) = n(h-1) + n(h-2) + 1  
    >= n(h-2) + n(h-2) + 1  
    >= 2n(h-2) + 1
    >= 2n(h-2)
```

After this step I don't understand the recurrence that would come here. I was reading a proof online and they did this:

```
>= 2n(h-2)
>= 2(2n(h-4))
>= 2(2(2n(h-6)))
```

I'm not understanding that block. Why is each step multiplied by 2 and why is 2 more subtracted each time from the height? I'm having trouble visualizing it or something. Then the rest of the proof shows:

```
>=(2^i)n(h-2i)
```

I understand how they got that answer based on the pattern, and I can solve the rest of the proof, but I don't understand how that recursive pattern was chosen. I hope I'm making sense. If anyone can clarify this for me, I would appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0):

Given that `n(h) >= 2n(h-2)` for all `h`, we can apply this very same inequality for `h-2` as well. This would give us:

```
n(h-2) >= 2n(h-2-2)
```

which is the same as

```
n(h-2) >= 2n(h-4).
```

If we now apply it again for `h-4` (as we did for `h-2`) we get

```
n(h-4) >= 2n(h-4-2) = 2n(h-6).
```

Now we can replace these two last inequalities into the first one:

```
n(h) >= 2n(h-2) >= 2(2n(h-4)) >= 2(2(2n(h-6)))
```

and so on...